# Can I use bootstrap popovers to display content with a Header (text and image) and a body ( text )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

My previous question was down voted because the question was not clear. Please clarify the premise.

Edit: Reference for how to popovers should function is from Apple iPhone AppStore-> Today (section)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDRIJh_5ICU

The video does not focus on just today(section) but entire Appstore. Please just refer the today section covered by the youtuber. Notice how a page pops out from the card, displaying Image in header and text in body.
My question is, Is there a way to display header (image) and body (text). These are the images:
**Before:**
[image: before]

**After clicking the card:**
[image]

Notice the popover contains image in it's header and text in body.

Is it possible to do this with bootstrap cards?

```
  <body>
     <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">   <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">   <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>   </div> </div> 
<body>
```

Comment: Post your code and a image of what you are trying to achieve or you will get downvoted again. Thanks

Comment: Oh! Is that why I was downvoted? ;D I'll post the image of what I'm trying to do or post a youtube video for reference.

Comment: Edited as requested with additional informational video and an image.

Comment: Why do not you use `modal` ? Popover has an arrow pointing to the element that activates it.

Comment: Write it as answer. I'll mark it as answer. :)
It's Perfect. LOL. Need to read entire bootstrap library then. ;)